# Behaviors missing in Blend and VS2013 for XAML project but present in Javascript project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-store-apps, blend

When I open up a XAML project, the Error list will report issues with all behaviors on each page I have open.  Examples of the are:

```
The name "EventTriggerBehavior" does not exist in the namespace "using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
The name "Interaction" does not exist in the namespace "using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
```

But I do have and confirmed the reference to BehaviorsXamlSDKManaged and the project does compile and run fine.

[image]

If I open up Blend, by either right clicking the solution explorer or opening it in windows explorer - Blend will report back the same errors and when I go to the Asset List - the behaviors will be blank

### [image: Blank Asset List]

If I create a Javascript version, all behaviors are found.

I am stumped after spending a few days on this, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

---- EDIT: I tried reinstalling VS2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to Visual Studio Update 2 - the issue was resolved.

Comment: it is back again... FML

Comment: Yes - still in Update 4

Comment: i'm having this issue now with vs2015, did you ever find a definitive fix?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the error by adding a reference to XAML Behaviors for both my Phone and Windows projects:
Add Reference -> Windows 8.1 -> Extensions -> Behaviors SDK (XAML). Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.Interaction is not included in the Windows 8.1 or Windows Phone 8.1 Core.

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.BlankPage1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <local:ItemClickedConverter x:Key="ItemClickedConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction 
                    Command="{Binding GoToContentCommand}" 
                    InputConverter="{StaticResource ItemClickedConverter}">
                </core:InvokeCommandAction>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: As you can see from the screenshot - it already has that done.  I am talking with Microsoft currently - they acknowledge it is some issue that is currently unknown but we are using debugdiag to identify it.  I will report my results once it is found.

Comment: I'm using version 12.0.0.0 and it's labeled Behaviors SDK (XAML) vs BehaviorsXamlSDKManaged. I thought by readding yours, it might upgrade to the correct version. I'll check back if mine breaks. Please follow up in this thread if you hear anything from Microsoft! Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft was unable to identify the issue but after updating to Visual Studio Update 2 - the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

How I resolved it:

- I uninstalled yet again
- Removed any extra apps that were related to VS2013 (addins, libraries, Xamarin, etc)
- Rebooted
- Ran registry cleaner
- Rebooted

Then re-installed with default options.

For good measure, I considered sacrificing a cow to the programming gods but elected to make them a strong pot of coffee.

Hope this helps someone else.

----- Updated details around Ran registry cleaner

I used the free version of Wise Registry Cleaner
http://www.wisecleaner.com/wiseregistrycleanerfree.html

It found numerous issues around the components and a few in the Uninstaller.  I often find the more elaborate applications leave old registry settings which make the re-install not accurately reflect a fresh installation.

Comment: Dave can you fill in the details of "Ran Registry Cleaner". I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that your project has a reference set for the Xaml Behaviors assembly. Right click on your project -> add -> reference. Check under Windows Phone 8.1 (or Assemblies) -> Extensions and check Behaviors SDK (XAML). I hope this helps.

Comment: I had done this - this appears to be something with the IDE.  See the first screenshot - it shows the assemblies referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project is targeting the 4.0 or 4.5 framework. If you target the 3.5 framework the behaviors will not be shown.

Comment: I was developing Windows 8.1 Store apps - so the framework was set to 4.5.1, so the change was not preventing the display for me but if it resolved your issue - great catch.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a project in Blend 2015.  The behaviours reappeared after adding these references (from Assemblies/Extensions)

- Microsoft.Expression.Interactions
- Microsoft.Expression.Prototyping.Interactivity
- System.Windows.Interactivity